# Determine if (x,y,z) point is inside a shape defined by an array of points

Tags: c#, arrays, point, shapes

If I have an array of points (x,y,z) and am given a single point (x,y,z), what code do I use to determine if that point resides within the shape defined by the array?

I am drawing a blank on this one...

I'm using C#

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses guys, from the comments I have found this link (http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) which explains the process quite well.

Thanks!

FYI:

```
bool pointInPolygon() {
    
      int      i, j=polySides-1 ;
      boolean  oddNodes=NO      ;
    
      for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
        if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y
        ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
          if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x) {
            oddNodes=!oddNodes; }}
        j=i; }
     
      return oddNodes; }
```

It'll need some work, but thats the guts of it.

Thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Point in polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243042/c-point-in-polygon)

Comment: This is a well known propblem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: Your problem is underspecified. How does the array define the shape? Is it the convex hull of the points in the array? Or is there some kind of multipatch triangle strip order which defines a polyhedron?

Comment: Maybe not quite an exact duplicate of the other post I found -- just noticed that Matt is looking for a solution in 3 dimensions.

Comment: @Jim, @Elian. No not it's not. It's point in POLYHEDRON. He has three dimensional coordinates.

Comment: @Elian: Does it differ when the shape is 3D? @Michal: not that simple; min/max XYZ gives you a "hitbox"; a cube within which the shape will fit. The point could be outside the shape but in the hitbox.

Comment: Ah I hadn't seen that Question when I searched.  Thanks for that..

Comment: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/insidepoly/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a point that you know is outside the shape, and check if the line from that point to the given point passes through the surfaces of the shape. If it passes through an odd number of surfaces, the given point is inside the shape.

Comment: Excellent answer, but actually doing this is harder than it sounds.

Comment: You have just created 3 new questions for Matt.

Comment: This is the method I'll use.. Thanks for your help

Comment: A better way of doing this might be to start with the point you want to test and keep increasing its x value in a loop. Every time your current position is over a wall coordinate, add 1 to your counter (unless the previous point was also a wall). If your counter is odd after you've iterated over your horizontal window, the original point was inside the shape. If the counter is even, the original point was outside the shape. You can make this method faster by using a QuadTree to check if a coordinate is a wall. You could also do a quick rectangle check at the start to dismiss far away points.

Comment: This is a 2D solution, but the conclusion is still valid. Pick a direciton and go, if there is an odd number of intersections, you are inside the shape, otherwise you aren't.  You just have to modify the if statements and loops appropriately to account for 3 dimensions, rather than 2.

Comment: @Nevyn: No, as stated it's a solution that is agnostic of dimensions. The solution works just as well with two or three dimensions, or even four or fourteen. The actual implementation gets more complicated with more dimensions, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Guffa's answer, it's harder than it sounds to determine if a line intersects a surface. Here's the math behind that: [Intersection of lines and planes](http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0104/algorithm_0104B.htm). You have to take that basic algorithm (which involves finding the normal of each surface to that point, then determining the angle between the normal and the line to form a right triangle that you find the third point of; WPF's Media3D library has functions on Points and Vectors that make all this easier), then determine if the point you found intersects the plane of the surface within the bounds of that surface. To do THAT, you can take any 2D projection of that surface that has an area > 0, and perform the "point in polygon" test, which is the 2D version of the "point in polyhedron" test you're trying to do.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing Shapes on a Canvas this is a quick and easy Solution.

```
    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is Polygon)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

"Polygon" can be any shape from System.Windows.Shapes.