# Algorithm to determine whether a point lies within a bounded area

Tags: c#, algorithm

How does one determine whether one or more points lie within an area whose boundary is given? For instance, in the following figure, three blue points lie within the area bounded in red, two red points lie within the area bounded in blue, and there are three points - two blue and one red - which do not lie within either of the indicated areas.

[image]

Comment: Search Google for Point in Polygon algorithms and you'll find a few.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Point in polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243042/c-point-in-polygon)

Comment: Have you some math definition of your polygons? In other words: is tgere any formula that you have that can describe them?

Comment: Thank you, Jens, it seems that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look [here](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/)
It's C, but code/algorithm can be converted to C# with ease.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a line from the point. check if it crosses any of the region edges and what side of the line it is.
If it crosses them odd number of times on each side it is in the region.

Comment: Not really true in case of concave surfaces. If you immagine a point out of the polygon but inside a "cave" , drawed line will cross polygon  but continue to be out of it

Comment: @Tigran, but again, it will first cross the cave wall, and then cross the polygon wall again on the way out which makes it 2 crosses which is not an odd number.

Comment: You can immagine that that immaginary line will cross 2 times on one side and 1 time exactly on vertex of the polygon. Just touching it...

Comment: @Tigran, if its touching a vertex if will cross both lines that make that vertex. for that there should be a special case that is not too hard to think of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "algorithm" to do this, but in C# (.NET framework) you could do it with `Region.IsVisible` method of the class [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Region_methods.aspx). You can create a custom region using [GraphicPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx) constructor. A GraphicPath itself could be constructed by a Point array.