# Latitude Longitude search from custom polygon MySQL

Tags: mysql, polygon, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geography

So I have an issue.  I am on GoDaddy shared hosting which is MySQL 5.5.43.  They do not currently support MySQL 5.6 on shared hosting apparently.

Now my problem is I need to search a database of 50,000+ latlng points using a custom polygon created by the user.  As I understand it, pre MySQL 5.6 only allowed bounding rectangle search.  Am I stuck running the search in MySQL in a bounding rectangle and then checking those results against a PHP algorithm to see if they reside in the custom polygon?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a user-defined function for that (see [Adding a New User-Defined Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html)) using [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673740/how-to-check-if-a-point-x-y-is-inside-a-polygon-in-the-cartesian-coordinate-sy)

Comment: well done, two alternative approaches to the user function are supplied