# Does a Google Maps polyline pass through any of the polygons held in my database?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, polyline

I am building a C# program that needs to determine if a journey passes through a zone.

I have a database storing 50+ polygons (the zones) in the format of:

```
Lat  |  Lng  |  ZoneName
```

I'm using the Google Directions API and decoding the overview_polyline response to receive a collection of Lat & Long coordinates that represent 'the journey'.

So, I need to check if the route (the journey) intersects with any of the polygon zones I have stored within the database.

I wonder if I should take the following approach:

1. Pull the zone coordinates out of the database to dynamically represent my polygon zone.
2. For each journey step, determine if the lat & long coordinate is inside that polygon

I see point 2 could be achieved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243042/c-sharp-point-in-polygon).

But that could be quite some processing.

A short journey returned about 300 odd lat/long coordinate 'steps' for the polyline & each polygon has about 10 or more lat/long coordinates that comprise the shape boundaries.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this please?

Comment: Can't you use SQL Server spatial types and then use `STIntersects` between your polyline (which you need to pass to a SP or similar) and the polygons?

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I hadn't even thought about it. I'll have a look into it. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. You'll get good performance out of it as well.

Comment: @MarcelN. your suggestion has taken me on an interesting journey and is easily the best approach for my needs. Could you please post post it as an answer so I can accept it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server's spatial data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) ([like `geometry` or `geography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)) to store the zones.

You can then use a function like [`STIntersects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx) to test an existing polyline against whatever is in the database.

In ADO.NET you can use spatial types via the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` NuGet package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx).

Comment: This proved to be far more efficient than attempting it in code.